# file.list method not working in java

Tags: java

I have created a dirctory named test. Within this directory I have created a file named test.txt. When I execute the program below, the output for list method on cmd does not show the list of files in test directory.

Following is my code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class f1{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    try{
        File f = new File("test");
                System.out.println(f.exists());
                System.out.println(f.isDirectory());
                System.out.println(f.isFile());
                System.out.println(f.list());
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

}

Following is the output:

```
 true
 true
 false
 [Ljava.io.File;@15db9742
```

Comment: It's an array of Strings, you need to iterate over it and print the elements separately. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-an-array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`file.list()` returns a `String[]`. Since arrays don't have an implementation of `toString()` (which is called when using `println`), it uses the default implementation of `Object`, which returns `ClassName`@`hashCode`. To convert an array to a String, you can use the `java.util.Arrays` class.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
// ...
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(file.list()));
```

Comment: Nicely Explained. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot print arrays directly. `File.list()` returns an array of Strings. There's a utility class `Arrays` which will allow you to print it without iterating over it manually:

```
Arrays.toString(f.list())
```

Answer (score 1):

`file.list()`

> Returns an array of strings naming the files and directories in the
>   directory denoted by this abstract pathname.

[Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

Answer (score -2):

list returns a string array.

so if you specify a correct file URI then it should work.

```
import java.io.*;

public class f1
{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try
        {
            File f = new File("test");
                    System.out.println(f.exists());
                    System.out.println(f.isDirectory());
                    System.out.println(f.isFile());
                    System.out.println(f.list());


                    for (int i = 0; i < f.list().length; i++)
                    {
                        System.out.println(f.list()[i]);
                    }
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really think you should call `f.list()` this many times instead of using a local variable?

Comment: Dude i am just giving an example.

Comment: And if you don't want to use a variable, at least use an enhanced `for`-loop.

Comment: it's a bloody example that only shows that it is a array of strings. he should find his own implementation.

Comment: It could also throw a NullPointerException: From [`File.list()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list()): If this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, then this method returns null

Comment: READ: so if you specify a correct file URI then it should work.

Comment: Chill I was just pointing it out.

Comment: downvoting isn't a way to point things out.

Comment: What tells you that I downvoted your answer?